# Запись цикла строк в массив

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

```
function links(){
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($this->url);

    $arr = array();

    foreach ($html->find('td[width=100%]') as $e) {
        $td = $e->innertext;
        $arr[] = $td;
    }

    foreach ($html->find('a') as $e) {
        $href = $e->href;
        $page = stristr($href, "page");
        $main = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $arr[2]);
        $page1 = stristr($main, $page);

        if ($page1 !== false) {
            $query = $this->pdoselect("*", "compr_pages", "page like '$page'");
            $pg = '';
            while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                if ($fetch['page'] == $page) {
                $pg = $page;
                }
            }
            if ($page == $pg) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                $pagearr = array($page);
                $lastpage = array();

                $lastpage = array_merge($pagearr);
                print_r ($lastpage);
                echo '<br/>';

      }
        }
        }


}
```

`

Возвращает мне цикл строк такого вида:

> Array ( [0] => page_36514.htm ) 
>   Array ( [0] => page_36511.htm ) 
>   Array ( [0] => page_36510.htm ) 
>   Array ( [0] => page_36512.htm ) 
>   Array ( [0] => page_36508.htm )

Но я всё не могу объединить результат выполнения этого кода в один массив, пробовал через foreach, но не выходит.

Использую библиотеку парсера `SIMPLE_HTML_DOM`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `array_push($arr, $link)`, а после этого возвращайте массив с значениями, которые Вам нужны.

```
function ($links) {
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        array_push($arr, $link);
    }
    return $arr; 
}
```

Comment: не подошел вариант, проблема заключается в том, что в функции результат анализа страниц возвращает результат в виде массы строк, при записи в массив внутри функции получается то, что указал в листинге, при попытке возвращения функции возвращается последняя строка этого цикла

Comment: @Krio, значит вы неправильно добавляете в массив

Comment: @Krio, можете дать сайт, с которого парсите?  Я напишу вам парсер.  Это не проблемно.

Comment: @Krio, или лучше напишите мне на почту romanko95.rk@gmail.com

Comment: Спасибо за отзывчивость, но мне нужен парсер на 12 сайтов, уже помогли разобраться

Comment: @Krio, да хоть на 120) Пишите на почту - чем смогу, тем помогу. Может что-то новое и аккуратнее придумаем.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код ничего вам не возвращает, просто выводит массивы с одним значением которое вы же туда и засунули `$pagearr = array($page);`. Перед `foreach ($html->find('a') as $e) {` создайте массив `$pages = [];` И в него добавляйте данный, за приделами цикла выведите его:

```
$pages = [];
foreach ($html->find('a') as $e) {
    ...
    $pages[] = $page;
    ...
}
print_r($pages);
```